# bower generates es6 export format Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, browser, gulp

I have inherited an old project which used gulp with angularjs.  It suddenly stopped working and the error I get on the browser is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` and the source code file is

```
export default function sha1(s) {
    return binToHex(core(fillString(s)));
}
```

The other error I get is `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`.  I feel the issue is something to do with gulp since the browser does not understand the syntax, however I could be wrong.  I tried fixing the gulp version to 3.9.1 without any success.  Any ideas anyone ?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Do you found any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

https://openbase.io/js/sha-1/contributors.
This library is upgraded recently and using export token.
https://github.com/linkgod/SHA-1.
Pin version to 0.1.1 in bower.json